# How To display different data on a tied anodes of 7 segment display

Tags: verilog

```
module main(
input [3:0] A, [3:0] B, S, clk,
output CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG, [3:0] an
);
reg CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG;
reg counter;
reg [3:0] an;

always @ (posedge clk)

    if (counter == 0) begin
        CA = (B == 4'd0 || B == 4'd2 || B == 4'd3 || B == 4'd5 || B == 4'd6 || B == 4'd7 || B == 4'd8 || B == 4'd9 || B == 4'd10 || B == 4'd12 || B == 4'd14 || B == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CB = (B == 4'd0 || B == 4'd1 || B == 4'd2 || B == 4'd3 || B == 4'd4 || B == 4'd7 || B == 4'd8 || B == 4'd9 || B == 4'd10 || B == 4'd13) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CC = (B == 4'd0 || B == 4'd1 || B == 4'd3 || B == 4'd4 || B == 4'd5 || B == 4'd6 || B == 4'd7 || B == 4'd8 || B == 4'd9 || B == 4'd10 || B == 4'd11 || B == 4'd13) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CD = (B == 4'd0 || B == 4'd2 || B == 4'd3 || B == 4'd5 || B == 4'd6 || B == 4'd8 || B == 4'd9 || B == 4'd11 || B == 4'd12 || B == 4'd13 || B == 4'd14) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CE = (B == 4'd0 || B == 4'd2 || B == 4'd6 || B == 4'd8 || B == 4'd10 || B == 4'd11 || B == 4'd12 || B == 4'd13 || B == 4'd14 || B == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CF = (B == 4'd0 || B == 4'd4 || B == 4'd5 || B == 4'd6 || B == 4'd8 || B == 4'd9 || B == 4'd10 || B == 4'd11 || B == 4'd12 || B == 4'd14 || B == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CG = (B == 4'd2 || B == 4'd3 || B == 4'd4 || B == 4'd5 || B == 4'd6 || B == 4'd8 || B == 4'd9 || B == 4'd10 || B == 4'd11 || B == 4'd13 || B == 4'd14|| B == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        an[0] = counter;
        an[1] = ~counter;
        counter<= counter + 1;
    end
    else begin
        CA = (A == 4'd0 || A == 4'd2 || A == 4'd3 || A == 4'd5 || A == 4'd6 || A == 4'd7 || A == 4'd8 || A == 4'd9 || A == 4'd10 || A == 4'd12 || A == 4'd14 || A == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CB = (A == 4'd0 || A == 4'd1 || A == 4'd2 || A == 4'd3 || A == 4'd4 || A == 4'd7 || A == 4'd8 || A == 4'd9 || A == 4'd10 || A == 4'd13) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CC = (A == 4'd0 || A == 4'd1 || A == 4'd3 || A == 4'd4 || A == 4'd5 || A == 4'd6 || A == 4'd7 || A == 4'd8 || A == 4'd9 || A == 4'd10 || A == 4'd11 || A == 4'd13) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CD = (A == 4'd0 || A == 4'd2 || A == 4'd3 || A == 4'd5 || A == 4'd6 || A == 4'd8 || A == 4'd9 || A == 4'd11 || A == 4'd12 || A == 4'd13 || A == 4'd14) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CE = (A == 4'd0 || A == 4'd2 || A == 4'd6 || A == 4'd8 || A == 4'd10 || A == 4'd11 || A == 4'd12 || A == 4'd13 || A == 4'd14 || A == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CF = (A == 4'd0 || A == 4'd4 || A == 4'd5 || A == 4'd6 || A == 4'd8 || A == 4'd9 || A == 4'd10 || A == 4'd11 || A == 4'd12 || A == 4'd14 || A == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        CG = (A == 4'd2 || A == 4'd3 || A == 4'd4 || A == 4'd5 || A == 4'd6 || A == 4'd8 || A == 4'd9 || A == 4'd10 || A == 4'd11 || A == 4'd13 || A == 4'd14|| A == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
        an[1] = counter;
        an[0] = ~counter;
        counter = 0;
    end

endmodule
```

That is my code but I can't never get it working.
I have no idea what clock signal is, my professor never taught us, but he expect his student to know that. I'm using the Basys 3 which has digits 7 segments display. What I have to do in order to make anode[1] display different result compare to anode[0]?
Please help me and thank you for helping me.

Comment: `an[1]` always equals `~an[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you are mixing the ANSI and non-ANSI port styles which is inferring `S` and `clk` to be 4-bit values. I suggest you change:

```
module main(
input [3:0] A, [3:0] B, S, clk, // S and clk are 4-bits here
output CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG, [3:0] an
);
reg CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG;
reg counter;
reg [3:0] an;
```

To the ANSI style below. Non-ANSI was required in IEEE Std 1364-1995. Since IEEE Std 1364-2001, support for ANSI was added. Many favor ANSI because you can define a ports name, direction and type in one line while non-ANSI took 3 lines.

```
module main(
  input [3:0] A, B,
  input [3:0] S, // not sure if you intend S as 4-bits or 1-bit
  input clk, // clock is single bit
  output reg CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG,
  output reg [3:0] an
);
reg counter; // you really want counter to be 1-bit wide?
```

With synchronous logic, you should use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) to avoid race conditions in the simulation scheduler. Using blocking assignments (`=`) with synchronous logic will not give you synthesis errors, but RTL and gate may give different functional results. RTL results across simulators could differ, even with in the same simulator depending how the indeterminate processing order between always blocks is programed. Use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) for synchronous logic the functionality mismatch virtually diapers. for more on blocking vs non-blocking read: [Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding, Styles That Kill!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf)

FYI: you have long conditional checks and the `? :` operator can create explicit muxes with some synthesizers. You might want to consider using the `!=` operator and invert with `~` or `!`. Example:

```
CA = (B == 4'd0 || B == 4'd2 || B == 4'd3 || B == 4'd5 || B == 4'd6 || B == 4'd7 || B == 4'd8 || B == 4'd9 || B == 4'd10 || B == 4'd12 || B == 4'd14 || B == 4'd15) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
```

To: (this is just a suggestion)

```
CA <= !(B !=4'd1 && B != 4'd4 && B != 4'd11 && B != 4'd13);
```

You are also never assigning `an[2]` and `an[3]`, and never using `S`. If it not used, then don't include or you will get warnings messages about it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you think my 2 digits 7 segments will display different data?

Comment: You should get warnings, but functionally it looks okay If `main` is your only module. If the outputs of `main` go another synchronous logic always-block, then you may see the functional miss match. It is better to fix it now and get into the habit of good coding practices.